# Trojans and generic suspicious malware blocked by MalwareByte while downloading blockchain

Tags: monerod

I am in the process of downloading the blockchain.  I am 90% finished but it is going very slowly.  I started 2 days ago.  Hopefully it will download fully.  I have the Monerod application as an exception in my Bitdefender and MalwareByte programs.  I have checked the Monerod application with Bitdefender and it came back "clean".  However, MalwareByte blocked 20+ websites because of Trojans and quarantined 3 suspicious malwares. Here are some of the IP addresses, all outbound, if it's any help:
IP address 5.9.109.205 Port 51538
IP address 37.59.56.102  Port 50881
IP address 5.9.109.205  Port 59114

Answer (score 1):

Those ports have nothing to do with monerod.
It is likely that your computer is infected with some kind of malware.
You should avoid using a spend wallet on this computer, keep it as a read-only/audit wallet here at best.
You may lose a bit of privacy but not your money doing so.

Anyway, I strongly advise you to format your disks & reinstall your operating system.

Regards.

Comment: I've used MalwareBytes and Bitdefender for years without problem.  I would know if my computer were infected.  It has to do with the downloading of the Monero blockchain somehow.

Comment: If those ports are destination ports, they are unlikely to be monerod connection to peers. And the blockchain itself is a bunch of raw bytes, no av or sandbox could have found a malware with them. Where did you download the monero binaries? getmonero.org? Github? Did you check the file signature?

Comment: I downloaded the binaries from "getmonero.org".  The last Trojan blocked was incoming, all the others were outgoing.  I'm not that computer savvy but wouldn't the IP address tell more than the port?  Here are the blocked website details from Malwarebytes: Category=Trojan  IP address=5.9.109.205  Port=18080  Type= Inbound Connection  File=C:\Users\CJ\Downloads\monero-gui-win-x64-V.0.13.04\monero-gui-v 0.13.0.4\monero.exe

Comment: Ok this inbound connection is indeed monerod. Port is often more relevant than IP, and 18080 is monero P2P. This is a false positive from your av. It may think that because an incoming connection arise the software is a trojan.